# re-format mysql field containing date information

Tags: php, mysql

I have a (suedo) date field in a mysql db that I would like to output in a different order. The current reads (2015-01-31) and I would like to change the output to (01-31-2015).  The current field is a varchar.

I have tried several things but nothing is working.  if I echo the date without formatting it loops through fine, but as soon as I add formatting it breaks.

$row_rsEvent[pubDate] is the field from the db

```
<?php do { ?>{
            title:"<?php echo $row_rsEvents['EventTitle']; ?>  - <?php echo date_format($row_rsEvents[pubDate], "m-d-Y")but; ?><br>", 
            speaker:"  <?php echo $row_rsEvents['speakerName']; ?>",
```

Comment: First bad idea is to store dates in a varchar field. dates should be stored as date, rendering it is another matter

Comment: I agree it was a bad idea. I've reset the field to a "date" field and the results are the same. input to the db is also the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the quote around pubDate and date_format needs the $row_rsEvents['pubDate'] to be an datetime object.

```
echo date_format($row_rsEvents[pubDate], "m-d-Y");
```

change that to

```
echo date_format(date_create($row_rsEvents['pubDate']), "m-d-Y");
```

Comment: Thanks.... That was the fix!!  Incidentally I tried this with datetime, date and varchar ojects and all three worked